# Python / Pandas: Convert 'Day of Year' Integer into Full Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I know with a Datetime object, I can extract the numeric day of year (e.g. January 1st = 1, December 31st = 365) with .dayofyear like this:

```
some_datetime.dayofyear
```

Is there a way I can reverse this and take an integer for the dayofyear and convert it back to a full date?

I searched through datetime and tried a few things, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Does the data include the year as well? Because without the year, how will you account for leap years? Leap years have 366 rather than 365 days, so if treated as any other year this would "overflow" and become Jan. 1!

Answer (score 3):

An interesting alternative is to use the `origin` parameter of pandas’ `to_datetime()` :

```
days = [32, 150, 200]
pd.to_datetime([d-1 for d in days], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('01-01-2020'))
```

Be sure to subtract one day since the first day is already accounted for in the initialization.

[Credits go there.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46858229/812102)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df['date'] = df['days'].apply(lambda x: dt + pd.Timedelta(f'{x}D'))
print(df)

   days       date
0    32 2020-02-02
1   150 2020-05-30
2   200 2020-07-19
```

---

**Sample Data**

```
# set some start date 
dt = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
df = pd.DataFrame({'days': [32, 150, 200]})
```

Comment: I believe one has to substract one day to the Timedelta since the first day is already accounted for in the Timestamp initialization : `(pd.to_datetime("2020-01-01")+pd.Timedelta(days=32)).dayofyear` returns 33, not 32.

Answer (score 0):

Does the data include the year as well? Because without the year, how will you account for leap years? Leap years have 366 rather than 365 days, so if treated as any other year this would "overflow" and become Jan. 1!

For example:

```py
s['M-D'] = pd.to_datetime(
    s['day'],
    format='%Y %j'
   ).dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

results in 366 being converted into '01-01'.

However, including the year works as expected:

```py
s['M-D'] = pd.to_datetime(
    ss['year'].astype(str) + ' ' + s['day'].astype(str),
    format='%Y %j'
   ).dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

results in 2015-12-31 when `year=2015` and `day=366`.